# Input rendering text larger than size defined in CSS

Tags: html, css

This seems really obscure to me but does anyone know why a font inside an input tag will display larger than defined if the font face is not defined in the CSS for the input element itself versus only the parent container or body tag?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cLffe/1/

I noticed this in Safari, Firefox and Chrome.  Is this a browser bug or am I missing something about default CSS for input elements?

Comment: I see no difference in your example in ff, chrome or ie9. Plus I read over your question several times to make sure I wasn't misreading. Both the p tag and input look the same size for me.

Comment: They looked the same to me as well.

Comment: Same for me; Firefox, Chrome, IE9, Opera and Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `<input>` does not inherit the font-face.
Short and to the point :)